# bpython in Emacs

Tags: python, emacs, bpython

I've started using [bpython](http://bpython-interpreter.org/) for my python interpreting needs.  I like the syntax highlighting and the tab completion mode.  I'd like to get bpython working in emacs (note: simply running the bpython command in shell mode doesn't work) so that I can achieve Python nirvana.  Any recommendations on how to get started writing an emacs plugin to do this?

Thanks,
Bradley Powers

Comment: You're aware of python mode for Emacs, right? It has syntax highlighting as well as several completion solutions (pycomplete, autocomplete, etc).

Comment: Yes, but I like bpython and would like to use it inside of emacs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`term-mode` works or are you striving for a integration with the python mode like sending code to bpython?

Comment: Or `M-x ansi-term`. Maybe [multi-term](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultiTerm) is also interesting for you.